# Fill a combobox from entity with translated labels coming from linked table in Symfony 2 forms

Tags: symfony-2.1

I'm trying to provide choice from an entity list in a Symfony 2 form like this :

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Country',
    'property' => '.....',
));
```

The problem is that the property is the label of the country in the current language, so it should do a query with join on language table.

Is there a way to do that without using "query_builder" option to keep the form relation between `User` and `Country` ?

Comment: Did you use the gedmo/DoctrineExtension?

Comment: Nope, my database schema is already made, i don't want doctrine putting his stuff in this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is fetch data with "query_builder" option (without forgetting to the "addSelect") and then use the "property" option to get first translation :

```
$builder
            ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'empty_value' => 'Select',
                'label' => 'form.country', 
                'class' => 'MySiteBundle:Pays', 
                'property' => 'fkLibTradG.trads[0].valeur', 
                'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->addSelect('tg')
                    ->addSelect('t')
                    ->join('p.fkLibTradG', 'tg')
                    ->join('tg.trads', 't')
                    ->where('t.fkLanguage = :language')
                    ->setParameter('language', 1)
                    ;

               }
            ))
           ;
```